# How to show how many people have viewed a post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a BBS forum, I just wondered how to count the views of a post?

I need to consider of both registered users and visitors.

I was thinking of counting IPs, but many users or visitors might come from a same IP. Then I am thinking of counting GA (as Google states every _ga lasts for 2 years).

I searched for a while, but have not found any examples.

Comment: Do you need a specific way of tracking visitors? Or do you want to track how many times the page was loaded?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I need to know how many users/visitors have read a post.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad, but generally speaking, you'll need some sort of middleware to run as part of the request pipeline and update some data store. If you're looking to discount multiple views by the same individual, then you'll need some sort of discriminator. That's where something like IP address would come in, but as you've mentioned it's not perfect and could end up lumping multiple people into one unit. The best approach is to set an identifier via a cookie, much as GA does with their tracking cookies. That identifier could be anything; it should just be unique for the cookie. `Guid.NewGuid()` should suffice. Then, you simply record this with the record of the view, and before saving a new record of a view, check for a record with that cookie value, first, if present.

A few things to bear in mind:

1. Instead of updating a single `ViewCount` column or something, you should track this in an external table that records the URL that was visited and any discriminating info such as the tracking cookie identifier. When you need to get a full count of views, just aggregate the count from this table. That will remove most of your concurrency worries. Otherwise, you'd have to gate writes to the `ViewCount` prop, or whatever, which will create choke point for your application.
2. Even a tracking cookie isn't perfect. For one, it will be device-specific, so the same user will be counted if they visit from both a desktop and mobile device, or even just multiple browsers on the same device. However, there's really not a better option here. If you do have an actual logged in user to work with, you can use that as a potential discriminator to get more exact counts, but of course, you still need a fallback option for anonymous users.

Comment: hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I was thinking of using Sql View, but the idea(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137189/entity-framework-core-use-include-on-querytypedatabase-view?noredirect=1#comment98936653_56137189) failed. The reason why I preferred to use a view was I dont want to get a list of posts and then iterate each of them to call getViews(). Do you have any suggestions?