# Entity Framework Core Use Include on QueryType(Database View)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have EF Core connected to MySql and I have a View called:

> PostViews

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012616/working-with-sql-views-in-entity-framework-core) saying I can use Query Types for Database Views.

It works if I just call _context.PostViews, but if I use Include on it like:

_context.PostViews.Include(xxxx), it throws me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Comment' is not a
>   navigation property of entity type 'PostWithViews'. The
>   'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of
>   navigation property names.'

[image]

PostView has all properties in Post (id, title, content, Comment etc.), plus it has one extra column called: Views which shows how many people have read this post.

---

Here is my Post:

```
public partial class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            Comment = new HashSet<Comment>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ApartmentId { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public bool? Disabled { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual Apartment Apartment { get; set; }
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
        public virtual PostCategory Category { get; set; }}
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

PostWithViews class is almost the same with Post but with 1 more property Views:

```
public int Views { get; set; }
```

Here is how I include properties e.g. Comment :

```
return GetAll()
       .Include(p => p.Author)
       .Include(p => p.Comment)
```

Comment: Exception message is telling you the problem. What is the **type** of the `Comment` property?

Comment: hi @IvanStoev  please see my update.

Comment: Hi, take a look at [Compare query types to entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types#compare-query-types-to-entity-types). You've probably missed the following bullet *"They can only contain reference navigation properties pointing to entities."*. So there is no way to make `Comment` included since it is a *collection* navigation property. But including `Apartment`, `Author` and `Category` should work.

Comment: hi @IvanStoev thanks for pointing out that point. could you please make it an answer, I'd like to mark it as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Currently (EF Core 2.x) query types do not support *collection navigation properties*, as mentioned in the [Compare query types to entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types#compare-query-types-to-entity-types) documentation topic:

> - They can only contain reference navigation properties pointing to entities.

So although your `Comment` property looks like collection navigation property, for EF Core it s isn't, hence cannot be used in `Include` / `ThenInclude` (or LINQ to Entities query).

However `Apartment`, `Author` and `Category` are *"reference navigation properties pointing to entities"*, so they should be fully functional.

Comment: So this is true for EF Core 3 also right? I am trying to 'fake' a naviation property by doing `var people = dbContext.People.Select(p => new { PersonName = p.Name, Cats = dbContext.AnimalsView.Where(a => a.Species == "cat" && a.OwnerID == p.ID }).ToArray() })`. But I only ever get one cat per person!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver (1) Looks like so (2) Quite surprising, definitely a bug.

Comment: ‘Animals’ is actually a view that has no key set (therefore can’t just use navigation props). If I run it ‘outside’ in a loop I get all the expected cats in the c# array and they’re all in the join in the executed sql.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Indeed, I meant you found yet another EF Core bug. Actually I'm getting not only one, but also one and the same cat per each person!

Comment: me-ow! Oh interesting. The first person’s cat or the last?

Comment: First (probably). Who cares, bug is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

an include function needs a query parameter but it still does not know its object so you need to use a lambda function to pass its object and the parameter you want

try it: _context.PostView.Include(lambda => lambda.Comment);